# Fourier Transform using code

Tags: fourier-transform

Can someone help me? I need to obtain the Fourier transform of the following function:

$$
    g_s(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \text{rect}(50(t - 20 \pi n))
$$

It could be solve by code, like in Mathematica of WolframAlpha or Scilab.

Comment: Start by computing the Fourier transform of $\text{rect}(a(t-b))$. This can be obtained from the [well-known result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function#Fourier_transform_of_the_rectangular_function) for $\mathcal{F}[\text{rect}(t)]$. Compare the result with the Fourier series of the [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb).

Comment: With those softwares, since they don't know distributions, I think you need to know that it corresponds to a Fourier series (same as the Fourier transform of the Dirac comb)